# LibGDX - InputListener bounds on Table

Tags: libgdx, tablelayout

I've set an InputListener on a Table with mouseMoved overridden. I'd like for the input to be received when the mouse is moved anywhere on the screen, but right now it only receives input when the mouse moves over the any of the widgets inside the table (see red box in screenshot).

```java
font = new BitmapFont( );
style = new Label.LabelStyle( font, Color.WHITE );

xLabel = new Label( "x: ", style );
yLabel = new Label( "y: ", style );
xNum = new Label( "0", style );
yNum = new Label( "0", style );

this.setFillParent( true );
System.out.println( this.getWidth() + ", " + this.getHeight() );

this.addListener(new InputListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        xNum.setText( String.valueOf( x ) );
        yNum.setText( String.valueOf( y ) );
        return true;
    }
});

this.left().top();
this.add(xLabel).padLeft( 5 );
this.add( xNum );
this.row();
this.add( yLabel ).padLeft( 5 );
this.add( yNum );

this.debug();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most libgdx `Actor's handle inputs by default,`Table`does not.

The reason:
In the constructor of`TablesetTouchable(Touchable.childrenOnly);`is called, which disables touchable for this widget, but enables it for its children. This is why input is only received over the`Table`s widgets.

`setTouchable( Touchable.enabled );` solves this problem

Comment: I don't think that enabeling touchable solves your problem. Read @BennX s solution. Set your `Stage` as the input processor and handle the input there. If you only want to use the input on the table you can easily ignore inputs on other widgets (i think disableing touchable is enough).

Comment: lol, yes it does. I tried it. It works and it is the correct method for me in my situation. Why is this downvoted when it is the solution? Setting the Stage to handle mouseMoved is one method, but not the correct one for my situation. Why does everyone on stack overflow downvote just because they think their answer is correct?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/zaxrsa seems like you are right. Widgets have touchable enabled by deffault, a table not (as much as i understand). I will edit your Answer to give some more details and i to be able to remove my silly downvote... But also note BennX's answer. It should be a possible solution to and may help you in future. Also if you allready read the docs, posting links to docs is always good, cause this answers should not only help you, but everybody with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Thats the regular function if you bind an InputListener to an widget. Sure it's bound to the Widget and nothing more. And so it's bound to the size of the widget.

If you want to listen to all events you need to write an `InputProcessor` and handle the events yourself. 
Use the InputProcessor Interface and add the processor to the gdx.

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(yourProcessor);
```

The Stage is already an input processor and fires all events to the actors that are at that position. You can use a Stage for a good eventhandling for example to get to know if some tile or some character is clicked. But if you like more complex things you create your own `InputProcessor`. But if you like to you can add an Listener to the Stage and get all move events. This meight be a solution too. `stage.addListener(listener);`

1. Also take a look at [Scene2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) at the listener and event section
   for more clarification.
2. Wiki [InputProcessor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

Else resize your Table to fit the screen size and you get all movements of the mouse. But i wouldnt recommend that. Everything you need to know for that you can find at the [git wiki from the Table layout](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout)

Comment: But the mouse is not outside the table. The table is the size of the screen so the mouse is within the bounds of the table.

Comment: And please, don't link to docs. I've read the docs and because the docs didn't help in my situation that is the reason I'm asking here.

Comment: Log the table size it doesn't seem to be as big as the screen or the listener just detect on widgets.I don't see any sizing to screen size and the debug doesn't show red boarders at the edges of your snapshot. As mentioned if you listen to movements of the whole screen you add an input processor for it. If you still need hits on the widgets use a inputmultiplexer. There are no link to docs.